# Jupyter Notebook running on GCP not showing output after reattach screen linux

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, gcp-notebook

I am using Google Cloud Platform to make a machine learning model for a problem. The dataset is huge and the model takes many hours to train.

I found the method where we can use `screen`command to keep the notebook running so that SSH doesn't terminate due to connection failure.

However, after I `detach` from screen and `reattach` again, the code stays running but the **output cells of the jupyter notebook disappears**.

How to make the output cells in the notebook appear after reattaching to the screen session later?

Note : I am new to GCP, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GCP's Datalab notebooks?  Those ones required you to use SSH to access your notebook.

I'd suggest instead using GCP's new [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/).  You can open those directly in your browser without needing SSH (and so you don't have to worry about SSH connection failures)